# Upload file via multipart request to google cloud storage with spring MVC

Tags: jsp, spring-mvc, google-app-engine, google-cloud-storage, multipartform-data

I'm trying with no success to upload files to my GCS via JSP.

using this html:

```
 <form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="/gcs/uploud/" method="POST">
Choose a file to upload: <input name="uploadedfile" type="file" /><br />
<input type="submit" value="Upload File" />
</form>
```

Controller:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("pages/gcs/*")
public class GoogleStorageController {

    public static final boolean SERVE_USING_BLOBSTORE_API = false;
      private final GcsService gcsService = GcsServiceFactory.createGcsService(new RetryParams.Builder()
              .initialRetryDelayMillis(10)
              .retryMaxAttempts(10)
              .totalRetryPeriodMillis(15000)
              .build());

      private static final int BUFFER_SIZE = 2 * 1024 * 1024;
      private static String BucketName = "XXXXXX";

    @RequestMapping(value ="*/*",method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public @ResponseBody String home(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) {

        GcsFileOptions instance = GcsFileOptions.getDefaultInstance();
        GcsFilename fileName = getFileName(req);
        GcsOutputChannel outputChannel;
        try {
            outputChannel = gcsService.createOrReplace(fileName, instance);
        copy(req.getInputStream(), Channels.newOutputStream(outputChannel));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return "successPage";
    }


      private GcsFilename getFileName(HttpServletRequest req) {
        return new GcsFilename(BucketName, "media");
      }

      /**
       * Transfer the data from the inputStream to the outputStream. Then close both streams.
       */
      private void copy(InputStream input, OutputStream output) throws IOException {
        try {
          byte[] buffer = new byte[BUFFER_SIZE];
          int bytesRead = input.read(buffer);
          while (bytesRead != -1) {
            output.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
            bytesRead = input.read(buffer);
          }
        } finally {
          input.close();
          output.close();
        }
      }
}
```

I got files in my GCS, but the headers aren't correct.

Do you have any idea ?
How should i handle to HTTP Header request?
How should i define the Content Type field?

Answer (score 0):

You're not setting any GcsFileOptions in `createOrReplace()`, so I would expect that your uploaded object would have entirely default values. Try something like this:

```
        GcsFileOptions.Builder options = new GcsFileOptions.Builder();
        options.mimeType("text/plain-or-whatever")
        outputChannel = gcsService.createOrReplace(fileName, options.build(), instance);
```